# jQuery Tabs hide after page loads

Tags: jquery, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jQuery tabs control on [www.quickerbook.imobisoft.eu](http://www.quickerbook.imobisoft.eu) . On top right corner, under “My Account” you can see tabs appear for some time and hide until the page loads completely. I tried so many Posts/Forums to fix the issue but because of beginner level in jQuery I am unable to fix the issue.

Please guide how can I hide the tabs? It should appear when user clicks on “My Account” tab.

Comment: Whats the problem? The tabs appear corretcly when you click the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'flash of unstyled content' is because the page displays before the javascript has javascript runs in the page.

I like to go for the modernizr approach of adding a classname to the root html element,  then using css to hide elements based on js being enabled.

So,  in your `<head>`

```
<script>document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].className = 'js'</script>
```

Then add this style to hide the tab:

```
.js #hidden1{display:none}
```

Comment: YOU ROCK MAN! it's working perfect. Great Thanks for the help.
Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

**On page Source at `Line: 63` (chrome browser).** You are hiding the tab after page loads using `.hide()`,

```
$('#hidden1,#hidden2,#hidden3').hide().click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();    ^^^^
});
```

Change it to,

```
$('#hidden1,#hidden2,#hidden3').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```